# Program significantly slower after making it multi-threaded?

Tags: python, urllib2, python-multithreading

*If I seem like a noob when I ask this question, it's because this is my first attempt at multi-threading. Sorry.*

Seeing as multi-threading is for making the process faster, I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong in this. First thing I noticed is that the **"main-thread"** thread is extremely slower than it should be (it's the only thread not using a proxy).

Before the process was multi-threaded, it would download about 10-15 images within a minute in the single process/thread. But now, the "multi-thread" (which is the only one that does not send HTTP requests through a proxy) is really never showing (as you can see: http://puu.sh/3KfwY.png). It should be the fastest thread!

I hope I explained my problem clearly. :S

P.S: On the start of the program, it downloads about 20 pictures within 15 seconds; however, after that initial startup, the program slows down drastically. Any ideas as to why this is?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import string
import os.path
import urllib.request
import threading
from time import gmtime, strftime, sleep
from random import choice

#list of our proxies
proxies = []

downloads = 1

#the number of files we want to download
target = int(sys.argv[1])

#argument 2 - proxies
try:
    sys.argv[2]
except:
    print('')
else:
    param = sys.argv[2]

    if param.find('.txt') != -1:
        print('Loading specified proxy list ('+ param +').')

        f = open(param, 'r+')
        print('Opening '+ f.name)
        proxylist = f.read()
        f.close()

        #split retrieved list by new line
        proxies = proxylist.split('\n')
    else:
        print('Single proxy specified.')
        proxies.append(param)


class thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ID, name, proxy):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = ID
        self.name = name
        self.downloads = 0
        self.proxy = proxy
        self.running = True
        self.fails = 0
    def run(self):
        global downloads

        if self.proxy != False:
            #id is always above one, so make the ID -1
            self.proxy = proxies[(self.id-1)]

            print(self.name +' initiating with proxy: '+self.proxy)

            #make our requests go through proxy
            self.p_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http' : self.proxy})
            self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(self.p_handler)
            urllib.request.install_opener(self.opener)
        else:
            print(self.name +' initiating without a proxy.')

        while downloads <= target and self.running:
            rstr = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for x in range(5))

            url = 'http://puu.sh/'+rstr
            filename = 'downloaded/'+ strftime('%Y %m %d %H-%M-%S', gmtime()) +'.png';

            try:
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
            except urllib.request.HTTPError:
                pass
            except IOError:
                if self.fails > 10:
                    print(self.name +': Proxy is not working. Stopping thread.')
                    self.running = False

                self.fails += 1
            except:
                pass
            else:
                print(self.name +': downloading '+ filename+'...' + str(downloads))

                #if self.downloads % 10 == 0:
                #    print(self.name +': Sleeping a bit.')
                #    sleep(60)

                downloads += 1
                self.downloads += 1
                sleep(5)

#lets create the "downloaded" folder if it does not exist
if not os.path.isdir('downloaded'):
    try:
        os.mkdir('downloaded')
    except:
        pass

#thread count
thread_count = 1

#create threads, and initiate them
try:
    thread(0, 'main-thread', False).start()

    for x in proxies:
        thread(thread_count, 'Thread-'+str(thread_count), proxies[(thread_count-1)]).start()
        thread_count += 1
except:
    print('Couldn\'t start threads.')
```

Comment: He's downloading Urls so he's io bound. But by doing them in parallel he should be much faster. In python, multithreading doesn't help when CPU bound because of the Gil.

Comment: @VaughnCato multi-threading should help when you are I/O-bound, not the other way around.

Comment: @mr2ert: How is multi-threading going to give him more bandwidth on his internet connection?

Comment: @VaughnCato: In Python, multithreading actually tends *not* to help CPU-bound programs due to the [global interpreter lock](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock). For such problems, [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) is recommended. Threading is recommended for [running multiple IO-bound tasks simultaneously](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). It won't increase your bandwidth, but if you can't fully utilize your connection with serial requests, parallel requests may be faster.

Comment: @VaughnCato I'm not saying it is.  The general rule of thumb is that multi-threading will actually slow down CPU-bound tasks (like computing prime numbers, etc.).  This is because of the GIL.

Comment: There is quite a bit of latency when fetching urls. You are dealing with the latency and capacity of all of the nodes along the way, especially whatever storage is backing the web server.

Comment: The 'sleep(5)' is part of the problem.

Comment: @mr2ert: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: @mr2ert So do I need to change to multiprocessing?

Comment: @tdelaney The sleep(5) is only specific to the thread, though? It only sleeps after it successfully downloads an image. So it doesn't get called THAT often.

Comment: @Justin I can't say for sure, but you should read [PEP-0371](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0371/) to help you decide.  Changing the code to use multiprocessing should only change a couple of lines, so I think it may be worth a try.

Comment: Make sure to read the performance tests on the PEP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the actual problem is, but one thing I noticed is that you use `urllib.request.install_opener`. That sets a default global opener, so every thread will see the change. It's likely that the first time through, most threads use the proxy they were assigned, but after that, all requests go to the same proxy, and you get throttled by the proxy or something.

The `sleep(5)` looks weird. That could easily be your problem.

You're using shared global variables with no locking. It might not bite you most of the time, but you're likely to get weird failures eventually unless you properly synchronize all simultaneous access to mutable state from different threads.

Comment: Yes, but it'll still make that thread sleep. Do you really want to do that?

Comment: It only sleeps after it successfully downloads an image. So it doesn't get called THAT often.

Comment: Whether sleep is a problem depends on the number of threads and the size of downloads. But 5 seconds is a lot.